# XeLaTeX RAM usage problem (bug?)

Tags: fonts, xetex, mac, memory

There is something wrong with Xe(La)TeX's memory-management with *some* fonts:

Compiling the following MWE with up-to-date xelatex on Mac OS X 10.7.5 uses up to 2.2 GB of the total 4 GB RAM available on my iMac and renders my older laptop with only 2 GB unusable.

Most other fonts (e.g. Linux Libertine) work as expected (ca 220 MB usage), but unfortunately not the proprietary one that I need. I have not been able to identify any pattern (ttf or ps-based, OT or not) of which ones work and which don't.

The problem neither affects lualatex and probably not other TeXLive-installations (only tested on Linux).

([This unanswered question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55839/excessive-input-causes-problems-in-xelatex?rq=1) might be caused by the same bug.)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setromanfont{Hoefler Text}
%%: works fine with e.g.
%\setromanfont{Linux Libertine}


\usepackage{ifthen}
\newcounter{ctra}
\setcounter{ctra}{1}



\usepackage{blindtext}


\begin{document}


\whiledo {\value{ctra} < 500}%
{%
{
\Blindtext
}%
\stepcounter {ctra}%
}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Your file compiles 721 pages (pages?), and then stops, both with lualatex and with xelatex. It is true that xelatex uses almost all my memory (2GB), but the machine does not become unresponsive.

Comment: The result of the compilation is fine here, too. This code is only a show-case for the problem that XeTeX hogs massive amounts of RAM when one uses certain fonts and the file gets big. If you increase the number of the iterations, you'll very soon get to a point where even new computers will take way too long to compile and get unresponsive.

Comment: If you compile with the switch `--no-pdf` it goes rather smoothly. Of course the trouble is caused by `xdvipdfmx`. Did you try to produce the xdv output and then process it with xdvipdfmx?

Comment: There seem to be a memory leak in the AAT code path, but I’m unable to trace it right now since xetex crashes under valgrind.

Comment: It turns out Apple’s Xcode has a nice memory debugging tool, using it I was able to plug most of the memory leaks keeping XeTeX’s memory usage around 185MB. Unfortunately, this will not solve your immediate issue and my only advice is to avoid AAT fonts for now.

Comment: Another option is to force the OpenType path (which has much less leaks) using `[Renderer=ICU]` fontspec option, but then you will lose all advanced typographic features (ligatures etc.).

Comment: Loosing the ligatures would be ok (tex-text will work for most Latin scripts at least), but `[Renderer=ICU]` also cancels the kerning-tables, which isn't an option for me. But I can work with it for the correcting/proofing, which will spare me a lot of time. If you say “for now” -- are we talking weeks, months or years? Just asking to be able to plan my way around the problem.

Comment: Rebuilding the fonts to OT-ttf would make the fonts work properly, wouldn't it? I have to talk with the designer about it... I also get the same leak with plain ttf (without OT). Does this mean that these are rendered by the AAT-engine?

Comment: The next binary update will be with the next TeX Live release, so that is around a year. Fonts without OpenType tables are rendered with the using the AAT code path indeed (this is the first time I realise this!), but forcing the OpenType engine here will lose you nothing (you would even get improved accent support for free).

Comment: Converting AAT layout tables to OpenType ones is not straight forward (there is not always a one to one mapping between both), but if you can do the conversion (or find existing OpenType versions) things should work. Alternatively, you can try building XeTeX from git (but it might have more bugs, I don’t know since it was not extensively tested).

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot confirm, that plain-ttf retains its kerning when handled by the OpenType engine. I've tried a couple of fonts here, but if you want to compare a readily available one, you could try [OpenBaskerville-0.0.75.ttf](http://get.schr.fr/open-baskerville/snapshots/latest): Adding `[Renderer=ICU]` to `\setromanfont` will cancel its (rudimentary) kerning on XeTeX 3.1415926-2.5-0.9999.3, fontspec v2.3c. Can this be because I'm still using Lion? While waiting for TeXLive 2014 I'll rather rebuild the fonts than using unreleased XeTeX -- I depend on this TeX-install to work...

Comment: Old-style `kern` table is supposed to work with OpenType renderer, but it seems I never actually tested it!

Comment: If you put the information from your comments into an answer, I'd be happy to accept that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There were some memory leaks in XeTeX code that handles AAT fonts, and they have been fixed in TeX Live 2014.